# Cannot persist child entity with OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, integration-testing, one-to-many

I want to create an integration test for a repository method which will find a trainings of trainer between two dates to check in the next step if the proposed date of training will not overlapping with trainer time-table.

The main assumption in the application is that the User is the main entity and from it the account, training etc. are created accordingly. For this reason, the User is an active side in relation to the account and training.

The method looks like below:

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT t FROM Training t INNER JOIN t.trainingParticipants p "
              + "WHERE p.trainer.id = :trainer_id "
              + "AND t.trainingDate.startDate <= :trainingStartDate "
              + "AND t.trainingDate.endDate <= :trainingEndDate ")
  List<Training> findTrainingOfTrainer(
      @Param("trainer_id") Long trainerId,
      @Param("trainingStartDate") LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      @Param("trainingEndDate") LocalDateTime trainingEndDate);
```

I am using this method in TrainingService like below:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
class TrainingService {

  private final TrainingRepository trainingRepository;
  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public TrainingService(TrainingRepository trainingRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.trainingRepository = trainingRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  public List<Training> findTrainingBetweenTwoDatesQuery(
      Long trainerId, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    return trainingRepository.findTrainingOfTrainer(trainerId, startDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

My `User.java` class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id", unique = true)
  private Account account;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private UserType userType;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Training> training;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "trainer")
  private TrainingParticipants trainingParticipants;

  public User() {}

  public User(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
  }

  public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
  }
}
```

Training.java class looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
public class Training extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "training_start_date")
  LocalDateTime trainingStartDate;

  @Column(name = "training_end_date")
  LocalDateTime trainingEndDate;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "training", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "difficulty_level")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DifficultyLevel difficultyLevel;

  @Column(name = "completed")
  boolean completed;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "training_participants_id", unique = true)
  private TrainingParticipants trainingParticipants;

  @Embedded private TrainingDate trainingDate;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private User user;

}
```

My test class looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TrainingServiceTest {

  @Autowired private TrainingRepository trainingRepository;

  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired private AccountRepository accountRepository;

  @Autowired private TrainingService trainingService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    trainingService = new TrainingService(trainingRepository, userRepository);
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnTrainerTrainingBetweenTwoDates() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    userRepository.saveAll(userWithTrainingDataStub());

    List<Training> trainingOfTrainer =
        trainingRepository.findTrainingOfTrainer(1L, now.minusDays(7), now.plusDays(7));

    assertEquals(4, userRepository.findAll().size());
    assertEquals(4, trainingRepository.findAll().size());
    assertEquals(2, trainingOfTrainer.size());
  }

  List<User> userWithTrainingDataStub() {

    User user4 = userRepository.saveAndFlush(
        User.builder()
            .account(Account.builder().build())
            .userType(UserType.TRAINER)
            .build());

    return List.of(
        User.builder()
            .account(Account.builder().build())
            .userType(UserType.TRAINEE)
            .training(
                newHashSet(
                    Training.builder()
                        .trainingParticipants(
                            TrainingParticipants.builder()
                                .trainer(user4)
                                .build())
                        .trainingDate(
                            TrainingDate.builder()
                                .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3))
                                .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2))
                                .build())
                        .build()))
            .build(),
        User.builder()
            .account(Account.builder().build())
            .userType(UserType.TRAINEE)
            .training(
                newHashSet(
                    Training.builder()
                        .trainingParticipants(
                            TrainingParticipants.builder()
                                .trainer(user4)
                                .build())
                        .trainingDate(
                            TrainingDate.builder()
                                .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(5))
                                .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3))
                                .build())
                        .build()))
            .build(),
        User.builder()
            .account(Account.builder().build())
            .userType(UserType.TRAINEE)
            .training(
                newHashSet(
                    Training.builder()
                        .trainingParticipants(
                            TrainingParticipants.builder()
                                .trainer(user4)
                                .build())
                        .trainingDate(
                            TrainingDate.builder()
                                .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(5))
                                .endDate(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3))
                                .build())
                        .build()))
            .build());

  }


}
```

Problem is that first assertion passes and I am able to save 4 users but second assertion: 
`assertEquals(4, trainingRepository.findAll().size());` 
fails and my trainings are not saved while user creation. All I want to do is to be able to save my training while creating a user. I am pretty sure that there is a problem with mapping User <-> Training but honestly, I don't see any other potential fix to reach a desirable goal. I will be grateful for suggestions about how to fix my mapping and get a possibility to persist in training while user creation.

Comment: You have no cascade=PERSIST on the OneToMany association, so persisting a user won't persist its trainings.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much for an answer. After adding persist on @OneToMany side I am receiving an exception: 
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.appplication.common.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.appplication.common.User`